# how to search for a word in a file and swap the line containing the word with the next line using tcl

Tags: tcl

I want to search for a word "VPEM" and if found swap it with the next line
for say if we find VPEM in 19 line swap line 19 and 20

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a moderately complex search-and-modify, we should read the file into memory and work on it there. Given that, we can then use `split` to make a list of lines, `lsearch -all` to find lines of interest, and `lset` to actually do the swaps.

```
# Read in; idiomatic
set f [open $theFile]
set lines [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

# \y is a word boundary constraint; perfect for what we want!
foreach idx [lsearch -all -regexp $lines {\yVPEM\y}] {
    # Do the swap; idiomatic
    set tmp [lindex $lines $idx]
    set i2 [expr {$idx + 1}]
    lset lines $idx [lindex $lines $i2]
    lset lines $i2 $tmp
}

# Write out; idiomatic
set f [open $theFile w]
puts -nonewline $f [join $lines "\n"]
close $f
```